# How to stream responses of a specific API that supports Server-Sent Events (SSE) in flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, server-sent-events

I'm trying to stream responses from a specific API that supports Server-Sent Events (SSE) in Flutter. Something like ChatGPT that shows the response little by little.

Specifically, I have a server created in python that returns the stream with yield. And I want to read it little by little in flutter.

Can someone guide me on how to do this in Flutter?
Thank you!

[gwhyyy](/questions/tagged/gwhyyy)

I've tried searching the internet for libraries, native solutions... but I can't find anything.

I have tried in web and android, it seems to me that in flutter web would not work...that's why I tried also in app.

The goal is to have my python server that returns the answers with yield gradually reflected in flutter gradually as for example ChatGPT that shows the answer as it is received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

To handle SSE / server responses as streams in Flutter, you can use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void establishSSEConnection() {
  http.Client client = http.Client();
  http.Request request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('YOUR_SSE_ENDPOINT'));

  StreamSubscription<http.Response> streamSubscription;
  
  streamSubscription = client.send(request).asStream().listen((response) {
    response.stream.listen((event) {
      // Handle the received event
      // The event will be of type http.StreamedResponse
      // You can extract data using event.stream or event.stream.bytesToString()
    }, onError: (error) {
      // Handle any error that occurs during the connection or data retrieval
    }, cancelOnError: true);
  }, onError: (error) {
    // Handle any error that occurs while establishing the connection
  });
}
```

Inside the `response.stream.listen` event of the `establishSSEConnection` function, you can handle the streamed data, response by response.

The code may need adjustments, but it's a starter example of this type of server subscription.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!!!
But not on the web, right?
Is there any way to make it work also on web?

Comment: The http package should also handle the connection on the web, and the provided solution should work fine. Maybe is there something else that is preventing the code to work on web?